# Connect to Raspberry PI over local network without adding .local

Tags: networking

I have a Raspberry PI Zero W configured as a Wi-Fi access point and running a web server. Its hostname is `a-casa-de-casario`. I can access my website perfectly from any other machine connected to the local network provided by the PI using the `a-casa-de-casario.local` address. But is there a way to get rid of the `.local` suffix so as to access the website using only the `a-casa-de-casario` address?

The PI Zero W is providing the access point through its wlan0 interface and is therefore not connected to any other network. Here is the relevant part of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` :

```
interface wlan0
  static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
  static domain_name_servers=192.168.4.1
  nohook wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: What is your network environment? The answer to this question highly depends on your dns server (most likely in your router/modem).

Comment: @UwePlonus Sorry. I edited the question and tried to add more information about the network environment.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `.local` DNS top-level domain. This domain is reserved for multicast DNS (**mDNS**) mostly used for [Link-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) and defined not be be served by any DNS server. This is managed by **avahi** and implies that there is no DHCP server present on the subnet and there is no DNS server serving the `.local` top level domain. All devices on the subnet have ip addresses from the subnet 169.254.0.0/16.

The local DNS resolver is managed with the file `/etc/resolv.conf`. You can tell the resolver to always append a default domain if the queried DNS name isn't full qualified. These options are

> **domain** Local domain name
>   **search** Search list for host-name lookup

For its specific use look at `man resolv.conf`. This way you can omit typing the domain name `.local`.

But there is a problem with modifying `/etc/resolv.conf`. This file is mostly modified by resolver configuration programs like `resolvconf` or `openresolv` or `systemd-resolved.service` to manage changed DNS server entries on mobile devices. They will always overwrite your settings in resolv.conf. You have to determine what configuration options of that programs will set **domain** and/or **search** entries in resolv.conf.

If you do not use a resolver configuration program you can just edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.

**UPDATE:**
I have learned that the description above is the default behavior with DNS name resolution but `.local` is a special top level domain that do not follow this. It is used as an parallel service to DNS with DNS server. Any DNS query for a name ending with `.local` MUST be sent to the **mDNS** IPv4 link-local multicast address 224.0.0.251. [<sup>**(2)**</sup>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457525/243074)

The `.local` domain should not be used when setting up DNS infra-structures. So a query to a DNS infra-structure should never give an answer. Most applications use glibc's Name Service Switch to decide how host names are looked up. This is configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and has a special entry for **mDNS** which ensures that a `.local` query is never asked to DNS server. For detailed info about this look at [<sup>**(1)**</sup>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457172/243074).

All together: you will not get an answer if you try to search a DNS infra-structure for the domain `.local`. The domain name itself is used to distinguish between **mDNS** and **DNS infra-structure**. You cannot omit it.

**References:**
(1) - [Can not resolve .local domains internal to my office LAN - Answer 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457172/243074)
(2) - [Can not resolve .local domains internal to my office LAN - Answer 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457525/243074)

Comment: Thanks for you informative and detailed answer. `/etc/resolv.conf` does indeed state that if was generated by `resolvconf`. As you suggested, I looked into its configuration file and added `search local' after the `name-servers 127.0.0.1` line. Now `search local` is added to `/etc/resolv.conf` but I still can't connect to `a-casa-de-casario` ( `a-casa-de-casario.local` still works, though ).

Comment: @Jujule With research to your comment I have learned the difference between **mDNS** and **DNS infra-structure**. I have updated the answer at the end.